# Creating vxworks file

Tags: vxworks

I am very new to vxworks and make files.

I have a batch file to run this below command

```
%GNUFILTER% C:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.3 make --no-print-directory BUILD_SPEC=PENTIUMgnu comp=kernel DEBUG_MODE=0 -f vsbuild.make %*
```

Can anyone explain me this command please?

This giving me an error message

> sh.exe stopped working" abnormal program termination
>       C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\make12099.sh: fork failed: no child processes [1]

Comment: Tip: don't hide critical part of your question somewhere off screen in a scrolling box.

Comment: C:\WindRiver\wrenv.exe -p vxworks-6.3 will set the environment for vxWorks-6.3, i hope the the exe's available at the same place from where you are running it. Next its trying to compile the code. First check whether wrenv.exe is setting correct environment variables WIND_BASE, WIND_HOME  etc.

Comment: I had a simmilar issue after switching from Windows XP to Windows 7. I found out that sh.exe somehow does strange things... To overcome this I've installed the current version of Cygwin and used the sh.exe included with Cygwin instead which solved my problems...

Answer (score 0):

Once I had a such error when I copied the workbench files into my computer instead of installing workbench. Reinstalling properly by installshield solved the problem.